# Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to solve this "destory method exception" with online tips but have no success. Here is the error message:

> 2017-10-16 15:58:13.234 ERROR 12276 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

And here is my POM.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

From online it seems the problem is at the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency. I tried older versions of the depenency, and clean mvn but none of them works.

### Update

After regenerate pom from spring initializr, I still got the same error. Here is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
<!--need this aws dependency for some packages-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--need this aws dependency for some packages-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have other dependencies? can you show your whole pom

Comment: you have  starter for multiple spring tools. I am assuming some version problems .  Run the command 'mvn dependency:tree ' and then check and remove all unnecssary dependencies

Comment: I ran mvn dependency: tree. The build passed with a success.

Comment: What I meant is Check your output of mvn dependency tree and you will notice if there are multiple jars . If you use  any ide such as eclipse, you can see in dependency hierarchy for Pom , and observe jars .

Comment: There is only one 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar got built.

Comment: @halfer Did you resolve the issue in the end? I'm experiencing the same issue but only if I run my JAR inside a Docker container on a certain system. Locally, the same container, runs without any issues.

Comment: @johannesboyne: I am the last editor of this question, not the author. The person you need to ping has their profile card on the right-hand side (`@genexu`). They last signed in December 18th, so may not respond to you quickly.

Comment: Sometimes, people who edit actually find an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many duplicate jars here ..

I would go [here](https://start.spring.io) to generate a spring project with required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue with exception

```
:Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized
```

and the error was in my declaration syntax of spring profile

```
@Profile({"production, dev"})
```

the correct way :

```
@Profile({"production","dev"})
```